# After doing save as .the excel format has changed ..any solution?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim workbThis As Workbook
Dim workbtarget As Workbook
'Dim RNG As Range
Dim PBR As Variant
' ASSIGN ROW FOR PAGEBREAK
PBR = Array(0, 38, 49, 38, 46, 38, 30, 52, 37, 42, 42, 42, 42, 33)
'    Calculate workbook manually
   With Application
       .Calculation = xlAutomatic
       .MaxChange = 0.001
       .CalculateBeforeSave = True
    End With
    
    Sheets(1).Select
    Calculate
        
    Set workbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    'Add workbook for copy data
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\Report " & Format(Now(), "mm_dd_yyyy_hh") & ".xlsx"
       'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name
   Set workbtarget = ActiveWorkbook
   workbThis.Activate
    Dim I As Integer
    'For I = 1 To workbThis.Sheets.Count
    
    ' Copy workbook data to another sheet
    Copy_sheet_data SH:=workbThis.Sheets("Report").Name, wbtarget:=workbtarget, wbThis:=workbThis
   
    'Next I
    'Next I
    
    'close the workbook
    workbtarget.Save
    workbtarget.Close
    workbThis.Save
    Set workbtarget = Nothing
    Set workbThis = Nothing
    'Save current workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    'Close workbook
    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Format can mean many things, what specifically is changing?

Comment: @NickSlash issue get resolved ..Thanks . format like word wrap ,column auto fit etc